# How to screenshot browser content using python PyWin32

Tags: python, browser, bitmap, screenshot, pywin32

When capturing a screenshot of a browser window (primarily Google Chrome) using PyWin32 it results in an empty image. Whereas capturing other console windows results in a successful image capture.

1) Why is capturing the bitmap from a browser different than capturing it from any other console window?

2) How can the goal of capturing a image from a browser be achieved without the use of other python libraries such as e.g. Selenium or browser extensions?

Notes; In my mind the RGB pixel information should be there and available, is this a problem with python not being able to render HTML? PyWin32 is used because speed is important. Code inspired by `nicholastsmith`

```
wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(self.Console_Handle_Window)
dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
cDC = dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, self.width, self.height)
cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
cDC.BitBlt((0,0), (self.width, self.height), dcObj, (self.FrameSurpluss_left, self.FrameSurpluss_top), win32con.SRCCOPY)

bmInfo = dataBitMap.GetInfo()
bmpstr = dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

im = np.frombuffer(dataBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True), dtype = np.uint8)

dcObj.DeleteDC()
cDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(self.Console_Handle_Window, wDC)
win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())

return im.reshape(bmInfo['bmHeight'], bmInfo['bmWidth'], 4)[:,:,:]
```

Comment: Your method may work for pure Win32 programs, like Notepad, but it won't work for browsers. You have to take screen shot of the whole desktop, so change `GetWindowDC` to `GetDC(0)`, make sure the browser is the top window.